# Error in Django when i use filter(sites__id__exac=...)

Tags: django, django-models

I have a four classes:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class B(models.Model):
    field2 = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class C(A,B):
    field3 = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and

```
class D(C):
    field4 = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

Only class D is in models.py in my app. Others is imported from diffrent files. Fields of classess A anb B are being used in many models. I created class D because i want to have generic admin panel from Django.

However, if i use this code:

```
obj = D()
model_class = obj.__class__
items = model_class.objects.filter(sites__id__exac=1)
```

i get the error:

```
Join on field 'id' not permitted. Did you misspell 'exac' for the lookup type?
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few letters:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#exact

More importantly, you shouldn't need to do an __exact on an ID field, just do:

```
items = model_class.objects.filter(sites__id=1)
```

or

```
items = model_class.objects.filter(sites__id__in=[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
D.objects.filter(sites__in=Site.objects.filter(id__in=[1,]))
```

Comment: ok, but why this should work and my not? I do not understand this. I have own model manager like this: mymanager(): kwargs['sites__id__exac'] = settings.SITE_ID return self.filter(**kwargs)